# Countable Dense Subset

Tags: functional-analysis

Do all finite dimensional normed space have a countable dense subset? If so, how would I go about proving this?

I'm pretty sure that they all do but I have no idea how to start this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you do it for $\mathbb{R}^n$ resp. $\mathbb{C}^n$? The construction can be transported to a general finite-dimensional normed space without much difficulty.

Comment: Not really. I don't really understand this at all.

Comment: Actually, I know I'm supposed to use something about the rationals... Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Q}$ is good. Start with $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can you guess a countable dense subset of that?

Comment: @DanielFischer How do you immediately see that any subfield of C has a countable dense subset?

Comment: I'm thinking $\{p+iq: $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}\}.$

Comment: @user2345215 $\mathbb{C}$ is second countable, hence all subspaces of it are too. Second countability implies separability.

Comment: I don't know what second countable is?

Comment: @maths1234 Good. Can you prove that that is dense?

Comment: @maths1234 The topology has a countable basis. That is, there is a countable family $\mathcal{B}$ of open sets such that every open set is a union of members of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: I am unsure how to show it is dense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ be a basis for the finite dimensional normed space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$.

Define $D:= \{ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iw_i : \alpha_i \in \mathbb{Q} \ \ \ \forall 1 \leq i \leq n\}.$

$D$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{Q}^n$, which is a countable set; so $D$ is countable.

Now let $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then for some $\lambda_1,...\lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$ we can write $x =\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iw_i$.   For each $1 \leq i \leq n$ pick an $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|\alpha_i - \lambda_i| < \epsilon/nK$, where

$$K:= \max\{\|w_i\| : 1 \leq i \leq n\}.$$

Define $y:= \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iw_i \in D$. Finally estimate as follows:

$$\|x - y \| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n|\alpha_i - \lambda_i|\cdot \|w_i\| < nK \frac{\epsilon}{nK}   = \epsilon .$$

Comment: How do you know that D has the same cardinaity as $\mathbb{Q}^n$?

Comment: $D$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{Q}^n$ because there are $n$ coefficients to choose and each lies in $\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathbb{Q}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$. So $\mathbb{Q}^n$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}^n$. And $\mathbb{N}^n$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$. So $D$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are equinumumerable, i.e. $D$ is countable. This is very basic set theory, usually covered in the first week of a maths undergraduate course.

Comment: Thanks. I'm clearly a useless maths student but I'm trying!

Comment: It's a pleasure. Don't worry, it's easy to miss obvious things sometimes.